# Name a directory with specific pattern in Unix

Tags: directory, rename

How can i rename a directory by interchanging the digits and word in directory name.

e.g.
FRA-DEV_007583-K4C-rdf-1
FRA-DEV_007583-K4C-source-8
FRA-DEV_007584-K4C-rdf-19
FRA-DEV_007584-K4C-rdf-8

output should be

FRA-DEV_007583-K4C-1-rdf
FRA-DEV_007583-K4C-8-source
FRA-DEV_007584-K4C-9-rdf
FRA-DEV_007584-K4C-8-rdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all those files in the same directory, with no other files in there, you could use this script:

```
#! /bin/bash

nums=(`ls $1 | cut -d- -f5`)
words=(`ls $1 | cut -d- -f4`)
files=(`ls $1 | cut -d- -f1-3`)
complete_files=(`ls $1`)

len=${#complete_files[@]}

for (( i=0; i<${len}; i++ ));
do
  newname=${files[$i]}-${nums[$i]}-${words[$i]}   
  mv $1${complete_files[$i]} $1$newname
done
```

Save this script as `rename.sh` in a directory OUTSIDE of the one where your files are. Then execute: `bash rename.sh path/to/your/files/` don't forget the final slash, and make a backup first just in case.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If an answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted (green tick). That gives you and the one who answers a reputation bonus.

Comment: Not sure which green tick you are talking about ? is it located top of the page.I can see one green and one red button.